# Failure to get media URL from LinkedIn Post API find by author

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to list the URLs of the assets posted to a LinkedIn organization. I use the [Post API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2022-09&tabs=http#find-posts-by-authors) to list the posts, and would like to use [response decoration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/decoration) on each post media, as such:

```
const url = new URL("https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts");

url.searchParams.append("q", "author");
url.searchParams.append("author", "urn:li:organization:2414183"); // DevTestCo
url.searchParams.append("isDsc", false);
url.searchParams.append("start", 0);
url.searchParams.append("count", 10);

url.searchParams.append(
    "projection",
    `(
            paging,
            elements(*(
                id,
                commentary,
                content(
                    media(
                        id~digitalmediaAsset:playableStreams
                    )
                )
            ))
        )`
);

const r = await axios.get(url.href, {
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
        "Linkedin-Version": "202209",
    },
});

console.log("posts response", r.data);
```

The request works (response 200, no errors), but the media are not decorated: the response does not include the expected `id~` field with media URLs.
As documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/digital-media-asset), I have tried decorating with `~`: it prints this error for images and videos:

```
...
"media": {
          "id": "urn:li:video:C4E05AQFvyswcWSMCJg",
          "id!": {
            "message": "Unsupported URN domain: li:video",
            "status": 501
          }
        }
...
```

I have tried to decorate with `~digitalmediaAsset:playableStreams` and `~digitalmediaAsset:privatePlayableStreams`: it does not decorate and does not print an error.

How can I obtain the posts's media URL without resorting to querying the images and videos one by one?